# Sorting on elastic search with node js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

For some reason, when I trying to search and sort from an index

This works:

```
GET indexName/_search
{      
    "sort": [{
      "_uid": { "order": "desc" }
    }],
    "size": 1

}
```

But, when using node js like this:

```
elasticClient.search({
     index: indexName,
     type: id,
     sort: [{ "_uid": { "order": "desc" } }],
     size: 1
 })
```

It returns an error:

```
No mapping found for [[object Object]] in order to sort on


status :400
```

I've tried `JSON.stringify` and all kind of other things, but none of them works

Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean? can you write an example?

Comment: Thanks !  Are you sure I have to have a body? there are examples there without a body. And also, when I remove the 'sort: [{ "_uid": { "order": "desc" } }]' line it works ok

Comment: Honestly, can you read the documentation? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-search

Comment: Thanks @Vsevolod Goloviznin, I've read the documentation, I've added a body, but unfortunately , I'm still getting the same error  - No mapping found for [[object Object]] in order to sort on

Comment: So, can you update your question with that you've tried?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
elasticClient.search({
     index: indexName,
     type: id,
     body: {
        sort: [{ "_uid": { "order": "desc" } }],
        size: 1,
        query: { match_all: {}}
     }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks @Vsevolod Goloviznin

Answer (score 8):

This also works with the square brackets around it so you can add more than one sort criteria like `['_uid:desc', 'id:asc']`

```
elasticClient.search({
         index: indexName,
         sort: ['_uid:desc'],
         type: id,
         body: {
            size: 1,
            query: { match_all: {}}
         }
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works :

```
elasticClient.search({
     index: indexName,
     sort: '_uid:desc',
     type: id,
     body: {
        size: 1,
        query: { match_all: {}}
     }
 })
```