# Sorting according to date not working in elastic search nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

i am trying to return all the data in descending order of date using elastic search in nodejs but not being able to. Here is my get query (it is inside app.get(/api/allAssets)):

```
let query={
    index: 'tokens',
    from: 0,
    size: 100,
    sort: [{"createdAt":{"order":"desc"}}]
}
// if(req.query.allTokens) query.q = `*${req.query.product}*`;
client.search(query)
    .then(resp => {
        return res.status(200).json({
            tokens: resp.hits.hits
        })
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            msg:'Error',
            err
        });
})
```

The portion where i push to elastic server is:

```
// index to elastic server
await client.index({
    index:"tokens",
    id: data.fingerprint,
    mappings:{
      properties:{
          createdAt: {
              type: "date",
              format: "strict_date_optional_time_nanos"
          }
      }
    },
    body:{
        "policyID": data.policyid,
        "metadata": data.metadata,
        "assetID": data.assetID,
        "name": data.name,
        "quantity": data.quantity,
        "createdAt": data.time,
        "fingerprint": data.fingerprint
    }
},function (err,resp,status) {
    console.log("response",resp);
    console.log("--------------------------------------------------------");
})
```

The code is working when i remove the sort portion from the client.search. The response is like this:

```
    "tokens": [
        {
            "_index": "tokens",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "asset1aq460y056c3mm4jmuv9vg39n7w8y5gykywjwge",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "policyID": "3a9241cd79895e3a8d65261b40077d4437ce71e9d7c8c6c00e3f658e",
                "metadata": null,
                "name": "Firstcoin",
                "quantity": "1",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-01T21:47:37.000Z",
                "fingerprint": "asset1aq460y056c3mm4jmuv9vg39n7w8y5gykywjwge"
            }
        },
]
```

but when i add `sort: [{"createdAt":{"order":"desc"}}]` so that i can return the response in descending order according to createdAt field, it gives an error like this:

```
{
    "msg": "Error",
    "err": {
        "msg": "[query_shard_exception] No mapping found for [[object Object]] in order to sort on, with { index_uuid=\"QcKwn0wtT-6cvdZ64RqVKw\" & index=\"tokens\" }",
        "path": "/tokens/_search",
        "query": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 100,
            "sort": "[object Object]"
        },
        "statusCode": 400,
        "response": "{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [[object Object]] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"QcKwn0wtT-6cvdZ64RqVKw\",\"index\":\"tokens\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"tokens\",\"node\":\"vIZfPrAnQRWqciWZYndxtg\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [[object Object]] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"QcKwn0wtT-6cvdZ64RqVKw\",\"index\":\"tokens\"}}]},\"status\":400}"
    }
}
```

Could someone help me on this? I am fairly new to elastic search and am stuck on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting on elastic search with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746994/sorting-on-elastic-search-with-node-js)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you. I have a question. Do i need to define that createdAt is a date object? Could you check the "mappings" inside "client.index" if it is correct? I am not sure how should i access the createdAt property and define it as a date object.

Comment: Pass it into new Date()